# How to apply different TAGs for AWS EC2 in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have applied the code for tagging AWS ec2 instances in Terraform, when the code runs it only created singe TAG.
How can we add multiple TAGs e.g

1. It add Auto creation DATE.
2. It add Auto OS detection (like it is windows or linux)

[Please see TAG detail in Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUFk1.png)

Gurus, your kind support will be highly appreciated.

I have added the following code for Tagging.

```
# Block for create EC2 Instance
resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  count                  = var.instance_count
  ami                    = "ami-005835d578c62050d"
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [var.security_group_id]
  subnet_id              = var.subnet_id
  key_name               = var.key
  **tags = {
    Name = "${var.name}-${count.index + 1}"**
  }
}
```

Comment: "when the code runs" - which code? Can you provide actual full code for the instance?

Comment: @Marcin apologies i missed the code. I have added now.

Comment: the tags attribute can take a map of tags, so you can put more than one tag key and value in this. I would steer away from using auto generated date as a tag, the reason being every time your terraform reruns, if your using a dynamic date generator that sets the date at terraform run time then it will think this resource needs modified and change the tag date.

Comment: @Marcin i have added below line for creation date and it is now showing the EC2 creation date.
  tags = {
    Name         = "${var.name}-${count.index + 1}"
    created-date = timestamp()

Comment: @ChrisDoyle let me check it by running the code multiple times. as i have added the creation date code.

Comment: Its not clear what do you want to do. What are the expected tags? What are the current tags that your code creates?

Comment: @Marcin i have used variable for TAG --->Name = "${var.name}-${count.index + 1} this will auto add the EC2 VM name in the TAG tab.  variable is linked with the Name of the VM variable. which is 
variable "name" {
  type        = string
  description = "Name of the EC2 instance"

Comment: So i just need to add some different tags from Terraform code, Name is already added, Creation Date is already added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tags`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#tags) attribute accepts a map of strings and you can also use terraform functions like [`merge`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/merge) to merge default tags if available in your used case with custom resource-specific tags.

```
# Block for create EC2 Instance
resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  count                  = var.instance_count
  ami                    = "ami-005835d578c62050d"
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [var.security_group_id]
  subnet_id              = var.subnet_id
  key_name               = var.key
  tags = merge(var.default_ec2_tags,
    {
      Name = "${var.name}-${count.index + 1}"
    }
  )
}

variable "default_ec2_tags" {
  type = map(string)
  description = "(optional) default tags for ec2 instances"
  default = {
    managed_by = "terraform"
    environment = "dev"
  }
}
```

Something very specific to `terraform-aws-provider` and a very handy feature is [`default_tags`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#default_tags) which you can configure on the provider level and these tags will be applied to all resources managed by the provider.

Click to view [Tutorial from hashicorp on default-tags-in-the-terraform-aws-provider](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/default-tags-in-the-terraform-aws-provider)

It's not possible to get the OS type tag natively as mentioned by @Marcin already in the comments.

Comment: Thank you so much Ishuar, please confirm do i have to add the line in all the blocks, for example, if i have three blocks, BLOCK 1, EC2, BLOCK 2 EC2 Private, BLOCK 3 EC2 PUBLIC.?

Comment: Great It created : Name : xyz, environment : dev, managed_by : terraform

Answer (score 1):

You can add other tags by simply adding to your `Tags`, For example:

```
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.name}-${count.index + 1}"
    CreationDate = timestamp()
    OS           = "Linux"
  }
```

Comment: Does this OS code line will pick the OS auto e.g if it is windows ami then it will detect add the TAG OS = 'Windowsxx'  and if it the OS will be Linux it will auto select the Linuxxyz ?

Comment: @Malik No. You have to provide it yourself.

Comment: Actually i need terraform to get the OS tag Auto like i did for NAME and CreationDate.

Comment: @Malik Not possibile without a custom solution, e.g. a custom `local-exec` or `user_data` script. You are hard coding `ami-005835d578c62050d`, so you may as well hardcode OS name.